# decoupling $scope.form from controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

In my angular controller, I have to reset some form fields to pristine at a certain point (when some other field changes). The code looks something like this ...

```
$scope.fieldCallback = function() {
  $scope.data.Field = undefined;
  $scope.form.field.$setPristine();
}
```

this of course causes problem once I run my unit tests, because form.field will only be there if you actually parse the document (which of course in the case of unit tests is not happening). I know it is possible to do something along the lines of

```
var element = angular.element(...[some html]...);
$compile(element)($scope);
```

but this does not really seem like a good solution to me.

Is there any way to decouple the controller from the html so I don't have to mock this like described above?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly getting your question, 
you could try implementing this while focus out of form

```
<form name="testForm" ... ... ng-blur="func()">
<input type="text" name="Field" />
</form
```

and in js file

```
$scope.func = function(){
   $scope.testForm.Field.$setPristine();
}
```

you can drirectly use expresion in ngBlur

```
ng-blur="focus=false"
```